# How do I return nodes with more than one relationship with Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to return a list of 'Group' nodes which have more than one 'Thing' node belonging to each of them. There are some duplicate relationships, so I'm counting DISTINCT Things. This query seems to work fine so far:

```
MATCH (n:Thing)-[r:BELONGS_TO]-(g:Group)
WITH g, count(DISTINCT n) as thing_cnt
WHERE thing_cnt > 1
RETURN g, thing_cnt ORDER BY thing_cnt
```

I'd like to be able to visualise all of these Group nodes and the Things that belong to them, so I tried this:

```
MATCH (n:Thing)-[r:BELONGS_TO]-(g:Group)
WITH g, count(DISTINCT n) as thing_cnt
WHERE thing_cnt > 1
RETURN n, g
```

But I get an error telling me that n is not defined. Can anyone suggest a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `WITH` clause needs to include `n`:

```
MATCH (n:Thing)-[r:BELONGS_TO]-(g:Group)
WITH n, g, count(DISTINCT n) as thing_cnt
WHERE thing_cnt > 1
RETURN n, g
```

As an aside, you should always specify the directionality of your relationships, if possible. For example, `(n:Thing)-[r:BELONGS_TO]->(g:Group)`. At the very least, that improves the readability and hum-understandability of your graph model. Also, it could speed up you query as well.

Comment: Hmmm I tried this but it returns 0 rows (whereas the first query, when I'm just asking it to return g, gives me 17 rows). Am I missing something else?
Also thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you specified the directionality of the relationship, make sure it is pointed in the correct direction. I had assumed `-[r:BELONGS_TO]->` was correct, but perhaps your data has it reversed: `<-[r:BELONGS_TO]-`.